Setting a ToggleSwitch on/off dynamically when the window loads
I have a ToggleSwitch defined in my XAML.
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="enable_toggle_button" Header="Turn on/off" OffContent="Disabled" OnContent="Enabled" IsOn="False" Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>

When my application loads up, I want to perform a check on my application. If my application is doing something, I want to auto set the toggle switch to on. If my app isn't doing something, I want it to set the toggle to off. Simple...
Inside the .cs constructor of my window, I have the following:
public home_page()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Task.Run(() => { set_enabled_disabled_switch(); });
}

Set_enabled_disabled_switch() then looks like this:
 private async Task set_enabled_disabled_switch()
 {
     bool is_it_running = await Ipc_handler.send_is_my_app_running_message() ;  // Under the covers, this send an IPC pipe message to a back end component, that then returns to tell my GUI app if its running or not.  it returns a true or false boolean. 

     if (is_it_running)
     {
         Trace.WriteLine("GUI:app is on, so enabling toggle switch", "info");
         enable_toggle_button.IsOn = true;
     }
     else
     {
         Trace.WriteLine("GUI: App is off, so disabling toggle switch", "info");
         enable_toggle_button.IsOn = false;
     }
 }

In my debug output, my Trace.Writelines are printing the right thing. But the enable_toggle_button.IsOn = true or false doesn't seem to be working. The Toggle switch in the GUI isn't changing accordingly.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

You need to be on the main (UI) thread to access the UI. You can check if you are on the main thread with the Threads Window.
For example:

Instead of calling a Task inside the constructor, try using the Loaded event, which will be running on the main thread.
public home_page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += home_page_Loaded;
}

private async void home_page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await set_enabled_disabled_switch();
}

If you need to access the UI in a thread that is not the main thread, you need to use the DispatcherQueue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73466419/2411960
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76866676/2411960


The line  Loaded += home_page_Loaded; is erroring in my code. says it doesnt exist in the current contect.  Edited it to be   Loaded += this.home_page_Loaded;`  and it worked. Hope this helps someone.

Thank you so much kind sir, you are a genuise.
